# Bad review audit, how can it be removed from the "audit queue"?

Tags: discussion, questions, review-audits

This question
[Why is C++20 std::source_location the better alternative for the predefined C++11 macros __FILE__ and __LINE__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970038/why-is-c20-stdsource-location-the-better-alternative-for-the-predefined-c1) was selected as a review audit for the reopen queue. Although it's not a bad question, it clearly asks multiple questions in one, so it would be a good candidate for the "Needs more focus" close reason.

I don't have much against the question, but how can we prevent from being used as a review audit, as it's clearly misleading the reviewer?

Comment: Because people upvoted it unanimously. There's 0 signal on that question that would tell the system there's something wrong. (until today)

Comment: Because review audits are procedurally chosen on basic characteristics such as state and votes

Comment: By voting to close it will have already been removed from the audit list (IIRC)

Comment: Seems I asked something in the title, and something else in the question, updated the title to better reflect the body of the question.

Comment: Looking at the history, it seems most people chose looks ok/leave open. though... there's no real way of knowing whether that's because they detected it was an audit or actually felt it was fine. In terms of the multiple questions in one bit... On the surface i want to agree, but given that all of the answers cover all of the questions without enumerating different answers within, I think it's safe to say this is an acceptable edge case. An edit may be helpful to alleviate that issue.

Comment: Meh. The question was fine. It wasn't anywhere close to being too broad; it only looked superficially like it because it broke sub-questions and follow-up questions down into a numbered list. Armed with a bit of topic-specific knowledge, you would have realized that there's no conceivable way that the question could be focused any more without becoming incoherent and losing context. Therefore, the correct answer was either "Skip" or "Edit", depending on your familiarity with C++. This didn't trip up any other reviewers, and certainly not any who knew C++.